# Remove Duplicate of bulk email received from different user

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

i have five user using outlook email client. Each of them receiving mails from a email marketing. i need to get all the unique mails from all my five user. i used the following,

> **Message-ID of outlook email** header.

if a same mail received to same user, then Message-ID is same. so that i can able to eliminate the duplicate mails.

if a same mail received to different user, then Message-ID is not same. so that i can able to eliminate the duplicate mails.

is there any better way to eliminate the duplicate mail from different user

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the message ID is exactly what you cannot use. It is always different. Check the properties of the emails and find similarities and check these. The first is going to be the From then Subject then maybe a part of the body.

Comment: if both subject or body contains Mail Merge fields (eg: Name of the Recipient), then how will we eliminate the duplicate

Comment: In general you are going to have to find the difference you can rely on.  If it is an automated email with very similar fields then focus on the differences.  I am sorry but there is no magic for the task you want to do.